# maven shade in multi project setup filtering too much

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

How to properly set up `maven-shade` plugin in a multi-module maven project setup?

#### storyline

A (https://github.com/DataSystemsLab/GeoSpark) has a dependency on B (https://github.com/jiayuasu/JTSplus) is a fork of C (com.vividsolutions.jts)

Now for some tasks in my project I need to use D (http://www.geotools.org) which depends on another Version of com.vividsolutions.jts.

How can I use both jars in a single project? A simple dependency replacement unfortunately does not work here. Shading should be the solution.

#### first attempt - shading the parent pom

When I try to apply the maven-shadeplugin to the root pom of https://github.com/DataSystemsLab/GeoSpark/blob/master/pom.xml as outlined [Using Maven shade plugin in a multi module project - NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147512/using-maven-shade-plugin-in-a-multi-module-project-nullpointerexception) a null pointer exception occurs

#### multi project setup

When following [How to configure Maven shade plugin in a multi-module project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021485/how-to-configure-maven-shade-plugin-in-a-multi-module-project) to set it up for a multi module build the maven build compiles at least. However, the generated jar is **lacking the actual code of the `geospark` module**. I can't see where this would be filtered.
My changes are available https://github.com/geoHeil/GeoSpark/commit/23d212aeeeacad8b7199da69366d583fc48edcf0

With the main changes being:

- introducing a third module `FinalModule`
- shading only enabled there replacing `com.vividsolutions.jts` with `com.vividsolutions.jtsgeospark`

Comment: I notice when disabling minifiaction of the jar: `<!--<minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>-->` the original code is not removed. Includes did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, disabling magnification is the solution. Otherwise probably explicitly including desired artifacts would work as well.